# How to get the checkbox value from a dynamically generated checkbox list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

Within a web form I am dynamically creating a series of chekboxes that are added to an asp:placeholder

```
//Generates the List of Entities that may be shared
        protected void GenerateEntityList(string agencyId, string agencyName)
        {
            var selectedAgency = UserFactory.GetAgencyAndSharedDataById(Convert.ToInt64(agencyId));

            entityContainer.Controls.Clear();

            //builds the entity list based upon entities in DB
            var currentEntities = UserFactory.GetEntityList();
            //add checkboxes
            entityContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<input type='checkbox' id='selectAllCB' value='All'>Select All<br/><br/>"));
            foreach (var item in currentEntities)
            {
                CheckBox entityCheckBox = new CheckBox();
                int currentItem = item.EntityTypeId.GetValueOrDefault(0);
                entityCheckBox.Text = item.EntityName.ToString();

                entityCheckBox.CssClass = "am_Checkbox";
                entityContainer.Controls.Add(entityCheckBox);
                entityContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/><br/>"));

                //mark checkboxes as checked if currently stored in the database
                if (selectedAgency.FirstOrDefault().SecurityDataShares != null && selectedAgency.FirstOrDefault().SecurityDataShares.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var ce in selectedAgency.FirstOrDefault().SecurityDataShares)
                    {
                        if (ce.EntityId == item.EntityId)
                        {
                            entityCheckBox.Checked = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Once created the user has the ability to make or remove selections. When clicking update I would like to return/collect the values from the checkboxes so that I may insert them back into the db.

```
//get the text value of every checkbox 
protected void updateEnties()
{
    string receivingAgency = ReceivingAgencyID;
    long contributingAgency = QueryID;

    List<string> cbValues = new List<string>();
    foreach (CheckBox currentItem in entityContainer.Controls)
    {
        cbValues.Add(currentItem.Text);
    }
}
```

However when I attempt to iterate over the collection I am not getting anything back which leads me to believe either I am calling the control incorrectly or it is being destroyed due to the postback. 
Instead of writing these elements to a place holder should I use another controls like a Listbox control?

Can someone please provide me with some guidance on how I can retrieving the checkbox values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two schools of thought; one, that you need to recreate the control hierarchy that was made for the initial view so that the page can restore the view state and form values into the control tree, or two, that you can go with a low tech solution and simply get the values from the form collection.

I personally, like option two, and it's relatively easy to deal with, and since it looks like you're already manually creating the HTML with `LiteralControl`. Simply provide a `name` attribute that is shared among your manually created input tags (example shown here for brevity, this is probably not what you will do):

```
entityContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<input type='checkbox' name='mySharedName' />");
```

Then, to get the values it is as simple as this:

```
 var selectedValues = Request.Form["mySharedName"];
 // This is now a comma separated list of values that was checked
```

Then you dont have to worry about the control tree state.

Comment: This seems to work okay but Request.Form only returns the value of "on" for selected form elements any suggestion on how to get the value back? Example Checkbox foo is checked how do I get 'var selectedValues' to show foo in the array vs on

Comment: Process of elimination. Of Z items, if you know X are checked, then (Z - X) are not checked. But this process is better when you simply want to know which items were checked.

Comment: Ah there is my issue. My list is being generated dynamically with linq and sorted alphabetically not necessarily how it is stored in the db or of fixed value I really need to derive both so that I can cross reference back to make sure I capture the correct checked element

Comment: You can always render a set of `<input type="hidden" value="X" name="anotherSharedKey" />` if you want all the values, regardless of check state.

Comment: Correct, if you have a hidden field, those will all be sent back to the server on post. So `Request.Form["anotherSharedKey"]` will tell you all the possible selections, and from that, the `mySharedName` comma list tells you which were selected.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you could make life much easier just using a `CheckBoxList` instead, and binding your result set to it. That would actually nullify the need for any dynamic content.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckList1" runat="server" DataTextField="TextColumn" DataValueField="ValueColumn" ...>
```

If that's not an option, then you need to recreate the controls after each postback. There are a couple ways to do this.

**The easy way**

Check out the [DynamicControlsPlaceHolder](http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx) control. This is a useful little control that takes care of persisting dynamic content behind the scenes. I would suggest this option, as it takes all of the pain away from dynamically created content.

**The manual way**

Recreate the control(s) during `OnInit`. Just make sure you assign the same ID to the controls so that ViewState can repopulate the selections:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    var chk = new CheckBox { ID = "chkBox1" };                 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(chk);

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

After recreating the control after the postback, you should be able to access the values like this:

```
foreach (CheckBox chk in PlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if (chk.Checked)
    {

    }     
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm missing something here this looks very direct but the foreach would go in my methods for click events correct? So to allow me to iterate through the list? is the above foreach supposed to be nested within another foreach statement. I ask as the code above references an object item with a selected property?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update that part of the example. Should be chk.Checked. My initial example was using a CheckBoxList. I updated my andswer, so it should be more clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your suggestions. Based upon how this was being implemented I credited Tejs with the answer as he sent me down the thought path for this solution.  In this project I needed to use checkboxes vs. a checkbox list control due to how I was building the list and verifying checked elements. The challenge came in with how asp.net generates the checkbox control as well as it's limitation on allowing the insertion of attributes to the control (name, value etc)

So to capture the vales from the code generated checkboxes I did the following:

Within the aspx file I added an hidden input field and assigned a runat=server tag

```
 <input id="cbEntityList" type="hidden" runat="server" value="" />
```

Tejs solution was similar to this but I didn't like the idea of adding a hidden field for each checkbox as that seems like a lot of elements in the page.

I then modifed the checkbox code generation piece to include as the Id a unique identifier from my object. ID gets rendered out in the html as the name attribute so this allows me to how have something I can retrieve with javascript /jQuery

So within the foreach statement where I would build the checkboxes I added the following line

```
entityCheckBox.ID = item.EntityId.ToString();
```

Finally I used jQuery to iterate the page for checkboxes and return a string array of only checked items.

This would populate back to the hidden filed a value such as (0,1,2,3,4) based upon what checkbox was selected.

```
$('#btnUpdateEntities').click(function (event) {
        var fields;
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            var txt = $("input[name='cbEntityList']");

            fields = ($(':checkbox:checked').map(function () {
                return this.name;
            }).get().join(","));

            $(txt).val(fields);
        });
    });
```

I could then access the array of values in my code behind as:

```
string voo = cbEntityList.Value;
```

Hope this helps any interested.

Answer (score -1):

This is the kind of thing for which you should put together an implementation using OO principles.  In this case, you should probably build your own CheckBoxCollection (inheriting from the proper interfaces/class).  It would simplify the code and make it more compartmentalized and extensible.

One of the implementation details is then handling the situation you describe:  throw in a click-handler that adds to the viewstate/session/whatever and you should be able to see whatever your test harness/users have checked/unchecked at a glance.

Another quick point:  you shouldn't use <br /> tags for layout anymore, especially if you're already using CSS.  You can make sure that checkboxen are whatever display type you need (block, in this case?), then set that in the CSS class with which you've already decorated the control.

tl;dr:  I don't have time to throw up an example in code, but the basic idea is that you should have a CheckBoxCollection() which (according to your preference) preserves its CheckBox()s' .Checked states from action to action.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the '<br/>' tag, I  removed them and updated the CSS to support the layout. Your suggestion was bit more than I needed as I did not want to get into using a click handler to check and update the viewstate/session on each click.

Comment: @JamesJohnson It's not, really - it's the "right" way to do it.  Part of the reason our profession sometimes produces suffering folk like me is that more people just throw junk code out there and leave it in production forever.

A properly factored solution is an happy solution.  ESPECIALLY when you have customized stuff, it's easier to manage in all kinds of ways when things are properly abstracted.

Glad you saw fit to downvote my answer without actually rebutting it somehow; very mature of you.

Comment: @rlcrews Why did you not want to add a handler for it?  It's trivial to do, and makes your code that much more understandable/maintainable down the line.  If you cobble something together that "works" yet isn't "standard," you'll confuse and frustrate anyone coming behind you in the codebase.

Comment: @Tonweight: I get what you were saying, but it is overkill if this is a "need it one time" type of situation. If it's going to be reused all over the place then sure, build a control. Even then though, there's already a `CheckBoxList` control that looks like it would accomodate OPs needs.

Comment: @Tonweight For my implementation I don't want to use a handler and contribute each checkbox selection to the viewstate.  I completely respect your opinion on what you see as the right way but I also feel that there are other alternative solutions that are also right and in some instances may be a better alternative.