# Access dynamically created checkbox values in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added a `CheckBox` dynamically in asp.net

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
cb.Text = "text";
cb.ID = "1";
```

I can access this `CheckBox` via c# in `pageLoad` itself, just after declaring above codes.
But when I try to access this values after a button click I'm getting null values.

```
CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)ph.FindControl("1");
Response.Write(cb1.Text);
   ph.Controls.Add(cb);
```

(`ph` is a placeholder)
Can any one tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: @mcalex its just a text

Comment: If you're creating the control tree dynamically, you must do so regardless of if Page.IsPostback == true, can you elaborate where do you create those controls (which event) ?

Comment: have you added the checkbox to the contols?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar Its added in the page load and is working greate

Comment: @NoIdeaForName yes..I will add the xtra codes to my question

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179589/how-to-get-the-checkbox-value-from-a-dynamically-generated-checkbox-list-in-asp?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you click the button it will post back the page which will refresh the state. If you want the values to be persistent then you'll need to have them backed inside the `ViewState` or similar.

```
private bool CheckBox1Checked
{
    get { return (ViewState["CheckBox1Checked"] as bool) ?? false; }
    set { ViewState["CheckBox1Checked"] = value; }
}

void Page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.Text = "text";
    cb.ID = "1";
    cb.Checked = CheckBox1Checked;
    cb.OnCheckedChanged += CheckBox1OnChecked;
    // Add cb to control etc..
}

void CheckBox1OnChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    CheckBox1Checked = cb.Checked;
}
```

Comment: at button click I can't even find these controls..that is what i am trying to sort out

Comment: IIRC when you click the button all the controls will be wiped out since the entire page is posted through a form.

Comment: I really want to persist those dynamically created controls there itself when I press the button..Is there any work around that will do the trick...else I am totally lost

Answer (score 2):

You need to recreate the checkbox everytime the page posts back, in `Page_Load` event, as it's dynamically added to page.

Then you can access the checkbox later in button click event.

// Hi here is updated sample code...
Source

```
<body>
    <form id="frmDynamicControl" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnGetCheckBoxValue" Text="Get Checkbox Value" runat="server" 
            onclick="btnGetCheckBoxValue_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.Text = "text";
    cb.ID = "1";
    frmDynamicControl.Controls.Add(cb);
}

protected void btnGetCheckBoxValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)Page.FindControl("1");
    // Use checkbox here...
    Response.Write(cb1.Text + ": " + cb1.Checked.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I am already doing it..The first three lines are inside page load.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit later here, but i just do:

```
try{
if(Request.Form[checkboxId].ToString()=="on")
{
//do whatever
}
}catch{}
```

If a checkbox is not checked, it will not appear in the Form request hence the try catch block. Its quick, simple, reusable, robust and most important, it just works!