# get code behind checkboxes in postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I want to add some checkboxes at the beginning of every row in a table in the page_load: (I add them in a asp:placeholder)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Table dtTable = new Table();
        TableHeaderRow dtHeaderRow = new TableHeaderRow();

        TableHeaderCell dtHeaderCheckbox = new TableHeaderCell();
        dtHeaderCheckbox.Controls.Add(dtHeaderCkBox);
        dtHeaderRow.Cells.Add(dtHeaderCheckbox);

        foreach (DataColumn col in _ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
                TableHeaderCell dtHeaderCell = new TableHeaderCell();
                dtHeaderCell.Text += col.ColumnName;
                dtHeaderRow.Cells.Add(dtHeaderCell);
        }

        dtTable.Rows.Add(dtHeaderRow);

        TableRow row;

        for (int i = 0; i < _ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            row = new TableRow();

            TableCell dtCell = new TableCell();
            CheckBox ckBox = new CheckBox();
            ckBox.ID = "chkBox_" + _ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["IDENTIFIER"].ToString();
            ckBox.AutoPostBack = false;
            ckBox.EnableViewState = false;

            dtCell.Controls.Add(ckBox);
            row.Cells.Add(dtCell);

            for (int j = 0; j < _ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Text = _ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString();

                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }

            dtTable.Rows.Add(row);

        }

        phUnconfirmedDiv.Controls.Add(dtTable);
    }
```

The problem is now, when the user press a submit button(and postback), I don't have access to my checkboxes:

```
    protected void btnAccept_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CheckBox> chkList = new List<CheckBox>();
        foreach (Control ctl in form1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctl is CheckBox)
            {
                if (ctl.ID.IndexOf("chkBox_") == 0)
                {
                    chkList.Add((CheckBox)ctl);
                }
            }
        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "event", "alert('" + chkList.Count + "');", true);
    }
```

Comment: Its not possible to maintain the dynamically created server side controls without re-creation. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992311/get-text-from-dynamically-created-textbox-in-asp-net

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get all Request.Params, which are created by the checked checkboxes? So all Request.Params starts with 'chkBox_'?

Comment: Hope this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968893/access-dynamically-created-checkbox-values-in-c-sharp

Comment: I don't know how many checkboxes get created, because the data are from a database. Could you give me a example of multiple checkboxes?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now managed to solve this problem. Thanks all for your tips!

All checkboxes that are checked are sent through the postback. So the "easiest" way is to search for all parameters, sent in postback, that are beginning like "chkBox_" and then save them in a list/array. So I know which data should be updated in my database:

```
    protected void btnAccept_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> chkList = new List<String>();

        //  All checked checkboxes are sent via the postback. Save this parameters in a list:
        foreach (string s in Request.Params.Keys)
        {
            if (s.ToString().IndexOf("chkBox_") == 0)
            {
                chkList.Add(s.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically generated controls lost their state once they are rendered on view. And for you, to access them again in your code-behind, when your postbacks, you will have to re-create them and after that you will be able to manipulate them.

As far as getting the checked values of the checkboxes is concerned, you could try something like this. This might not be exact, should give an idea though.

This would be your check-box :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="yourId" name="selectedIds" value="someValue"/>
```

In your codebehind :

```
value = Request.Form["selectedIds"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the full name of the checkboxes.. They all start with 'chkBox_' followed by a random number. Lets say like a timestamp. Is there a possibility to search all Request.Form starting with 'chkBox_'?

Comment: How about using `CheckBoxList` from the initial stage ?

Comment: That was my first try, but I couldn't add only one item of the list to each row. All items was added in only one cell of the table..

Comment: Is using `table` mandatory in your case or you could also achieve the samething with `GridView` control and resolve this.

Comment: In fact I never used GridView before. So when I use GridView then I can also use CheckBoxList?

Comment: The requirement that you have, putting one check-box in one row, can be easily handled using `GridView` and plus, you can use `FindControl` on that `GridView` to uniquely identify and fetch any Check-box in that `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

Is autopostback set to true on the user interface controls for the button? ei:

`<telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="rBtnRelease" Text="Release" Width="100px" OnClick="rBtnRelease_Click" AutoPostBack="False"/>`

That's usually the common mistake when one tries to get data back and forth between the client and the server side.

Comment: Sorry zeroOne, I meant set it to true.